# При попытке удалить запись выдаёт Page not found (404) и сама запись не удаляется

Tags: python-3.x, django

**Файл view.py**

```
from django.views.generic.edit import
from .models import Story, Rubric

class StoryDeleteView(DeleteView):
model = Story
success_url = '/'

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    context['rubrics'] = Rubric.objects.all()
    return context
```

**Файл urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import StoryDeleteView
urlpatterns = [
    path('delete/<int:pk>/', StoryDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete'),
]
```

**Файл story_confirm_delete.html**

```
{% extends 'layout/basic.html'%}

{%block title%}Удаление объявления{%endblock%}

{% block content %}
<h2>Удаление обявлений</h2>
<p>Рубрика:{{story.rubric.name}}</p>
<p>Товар:{{story.title}}</p>
<p>{{story.content}}</p>
<p>Цена:{{story.price}}</p>
<form action="POST">
    {%csrf_token%}
    <input type="submit" value="Удалить">
</form>
{%endblock%}
```

[image: Screen]

Comment: В форме, вместо `action`, напиши `method`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле `story_confirm_delete.html` вместо `action` укажи `method` в `<form>`:

```
{% extends 'layout/basic.html' %}

{% block title %}Удаление объявления{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Удаление обявлений</h2>
<p>Рубрика:{{ story.rubric.name }}</p>
<p>Товар:{{ story.title }}</p>
<p>{{ story.content }}</p>
<p>Цена:{{ story.price }}</p>
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Удалить">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```